# Input losing focus on change

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I am having some trouble working out the solution to this. I'm following the same pattern I've used for select for an input, but it is losing focus as soon as I type a character.

I've read a few questions on this topic but none of the answers I see are giving me a solution. I understand why it is happening - the change handler sets state so the component is rendered again. I just don't get how to fix it. I've tried setting a stable key to no avail. I also just pulled the value manually during form submit but I lose the ability to set a default value in that case. This feels fairly basic so hopefully there's an easy fix! Thanks in advance.

```
return (
    <Authenticator>
        <CContainer>
            <CForm onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
                <CContainer>
                    <CRow className="align-items-center">
                        <CCol>
                            <CFormInput
                                type="number"
                                id="quantityToAdd"
                                label={`Quantity (${this.state.formStockUnitName})`}
                                placeholder="100"
                                onChange={this.changeQtyValue}
                                value={this.state.formQuantity}
                            />
                        </CCol>
                        <CCol>
                            <CFormLabel htmlFor="expiryDate">Expiry Date</CFormLabel>
                            <DatePicker className='form-control' id="expiryDate" selected={this.state.formExpiry} onChange={this.changeExpiryDate} />
                        </CCol>
                        <CCol><CButton className='float-end' type="submit" color="primary">Add</CButton></CCol>
                    </CRow>
                </CContainer>
            </CForm>
        </CContainer>
    </Authenticator >
)
```

State handler for the input change:

```
changeQtyValue = async (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({ formQuantity: event.target.value });
    }
```

Also the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            formStockName: '',
            formStockUnitName: '',
            formExpiry: '',
            formQuantity: '',
            components: [],
        };
    }
```

Comment: can you show your state logic ?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal I added some info now, TY

Comment: formQuantity contains your value then why you don't set a default value instead of an empty string in it.

Comment: Could you not bind state to value? I mean, could you avoid `value={this.state.formQuantity}`? Because you're anyway getting this value in your `changeQtyValue` from `event.target`.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal that works for default sure, but I still have my core problem.

Comment: @AnindyaDey that results in the same defocusing behaviour, just the control never shows any value.

Comment: Why did you define your onChange function as an async function? Can you please remove async and try again?

Comment: @MuratÇelik mostly a copy paste from another. Removing async doesn't change the behaviour I'm afraid

Comment: Did you try to memoize CFormInput with PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate?

Comment: @stevepkr84 could you create a minimal repro, please? I have created a very tiny representation of what I was saying [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twekej?file=src/App.js), and the "focusing" seems to work as expected. Not sure what is going on in your app. so a minimal repro would be of great help to us.

Comment: @AnindyaDey thank you. I resolved this and posted below on how. Can't say I understand it fully, but I can move on!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. Through trial and error I worked out that the top level Authenticator component triggered this behaviour. I don't entirely understand why - but wrapping this way gave me a super simple way of protecting views by auth. I refactored to achieve this via another means and dropped the component and it works as expected now.

For ref this is the component: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/components/authenticator